# ¿Que hay que poner dentro de fgets()? Linux

Tags: c, string

mi consulta es ¿ que tengo que poner dentro de fgets()?. Ya que estamos viendo strings en clases y el profesor usar gets(), ya que usa windows, pero como estoy en **Linux** me dijo que debia poner fgets(), pero  al compilarlo en GCC me muestra el siguiente error:

> contarCaracteres.c:10:2: error: too few arguments to function ‘fgets’

El algoritmo que estoy haciendo es simplemente para contar caracteres, y la palabra es leida por teclado:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    char cadena[20];
    int i, contador=0;

    printf("\nIngrese la palabra: ");
    scanf("%s", cadena);
    fgets();

    for (i=0; i<20 && cadena[i]!='\0' ; i++)
        contador++;
}
```

Mi pregunta es ¿que debo poner dentro del fgets()?.

PD: No podemos usar funciones, ni tampoco librerias como string.h

Comment: Vamos a comenzar por informarte que la función fgets es para leer dentro de un archivo, que como sabras no es tu caso, si quieres informarte mas puedes visitar http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/ y https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/fgets-gets-c-language/

Comment: Vale, mi error. ¿Cual comando debería poner para leer la cadena correctamente?

Comment: Con scanf que es el problema que tienes, no respeta los espacios???

Comment: No, no hay ningun problema con el codigo, mi duda es si es necesario poner gets (o algo por el estilo). Ya que elimine fgets() del codigo y funciona sin ningun problema. Al parecer no es necesario algún comando para poder leer (como gets) la cadena. ¿Estoy en lo correcto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacer lo siguiente para usar fgets, Elimina el `scanf` y el código de `fgets` seria de esta manera:

```
fgets(cadena, 20, stdin);
```

O puedes seguir usando `scanf` removiendo el `fgets` de esta manera:

```
scanf("%[^\n]%*c", cadena);
```

Aqui puedes ver una explicación mas detallada: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6282198/reading-string-from-input-with-space-character

Comment: Muchas gracias Dariel, ahí me funciono. Leeré para poder seguir haciendo los ejercicios.

Comment: Si te funciona porfa marcala como correcta asi otros sabran que esta respuesta solucionó tu problema ;)